# How to print specific number of lines in python?

Tags: python

Suppose below is the String of 3 sentences

```
q="Widows and orphans occur when the first line of a paragraph is the last in a column or page, or when the last line of a paragraph is the first line of a new column or page.The function of a paragraph is to mark a pause, setting the paragraph apart from what precedes it. If a paragraph is preceded by a title or subhead, the indent is superfluous and can therefore be omitted."
```

If the user wants first sentence, It should print first sentence. If the user wants 2 sentences, it should print starting 2 sentences

I already done this with the nltk but is it possible with any other method?

Comment: Just split on `.` to get individual sentences?

Comment: Why do you need another way if the first one works? Please explain what's wrong with nltk that makes you not want to use it.

Comment: @SteeveDroz because I want it on android and I am getting permission denied error while downloading putnk from nltk

Comment: Good reason, you should put it in the question, that may have an influence.

Comment: This is actually a question of how to judge the sentence boundary. Only '.' is not robust, because a sentence may end with other characters, e.g., '?'. Besides, '.' occurs in the middle of my last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

like Aran-Fey suggested you can use the String.split() function as follows :

```
print(q.split("."))
```

And maybe add conditions depending on what the user inputs.

Basically the split function creates an array of a string, and separates the strings using the provided parameter into multiple elements of the array.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_list = q.split(".")
```

now you have new list with n number of line, just used list indexing to print particular line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split() function

```
string.split()[:num]
```

For example

```
string="hello stack overflow"
print(string.split()[:2])
```

Output: ['hello', 'stack']